# Display the content of a form in a new page using WordPress

Tags: wordpress, forms

I am trying to display the content of a form in new page using WordPress but I could not
can anyone help please?

I used the Forminator form and still did not got my expectation
my expectation is to see the data that been submitted in the new Page as a list

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.